# String separator for words

Tags: java, string

I wanted to know how to separate the words in a String for example
if I have a string

```
str = "This is a computer";
```

I want to implement a method in each of the words of the string separately and the space is going to be the separator. After that I want to return the words in the implemented way in an only new `String`.

Comment: can u be specific what u mean by "return the words in the implemented way in an only new String" ? and show your code too

Comment: by that I mean that after implementing the method in each word of the string i ant to return the words in a single new String which is going to have the implemented words from the previous string. Do you need any more info? And btw I haven't written any code for this yet because this is what I am asking help for.

Comment: @AngadTiwari I am writing a message encrypment program. I know how to do it for one word but I need to do it for the entire message.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `string.Split` method, for sample:

```
String str  = "This is a computer"; 

String[] parts = str.split("[\\W]");

// iterate in the parts array and print each item from string
for(String word : parts){
   System.out.println(word);
}
```

To do the reverse way, to join all items from an array into a string, you could use `string.Join`, for sample:

```
String[] words = new String[] { "This", "is", "a", "computer" };

// you pass the separator (space) and the array
String phrase = String.join(" ", words);
```